# Google's onSuccessHandler not responding

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, handler

I have written a javascript in an html file that I linked to my google spreadsheet.
It is all working well, and the script does what it needs to do, taking certain values from the html and filling it in certain fields in the sheet, but there is no success message coming back and the user is led to a blank page.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

HTML code:

```
<script>
function onSuccess() {window.confirm("Your order was successfully sent");}
function onFailure() {window.confirm("Something went wrong. Please try again or contact the Customer Service.");}

function PR(){
if (window.confirm("Send Order?")) {

var k = document.getElementById('custname').value;
var l = document.getElementById('mayor').value;
var m = document.getElementById('ioc').value;
var n = document.getElementById('canpen').value;
var o = document.getElementById('date').value;
var p = document.getElementById('idcie').value;
var q = document.getElementById('totdes').value;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).copyData(k,l,m,n,o,p,q);

} 
else {alert("You canceled your order, try again!");}
}

</script>
```

GOOGLE SCRIPT:

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page')
      .evaluate();
      
}


function copyData(k,l,m,n,o,p,q) {
DB.getRange(1,3).setValue(l);
DB.getRange(1,4).setValue(m);
DB.getRange(1,5).setValue(p);
DB.getRange(1,6).setValue(n);
DB.getRange(1,7).setValue(o);
DB.getRange(1,8).setValue(q);

}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the method for executing the function of `PR()`?

Comment: try adding not nullable `return` statement to `copyData` function

Comment: Can you update your question with the logs from the console that you see in the `console` tab when `F12` is pressed?

Comment: hi @Tanaike: what do you mean with method? it is a button with onclick ref to the function

Comment: hi @Dmitro: I have added a return to the function but no luck - how would you do it?

Comment: hi @Rafa : the console goes too quick from pressing the button to the blank page, so i cannot see or save it

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the script for replicating your issue?

Comment: @KoenCabus The console allows scrolling so you can scroll up in order to view the messages